# Line chart customization using D3.js and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, ionic-framework

I am developing a line chart using D3.js library and AngularJS in Ionic.
I want to customize the colour of data point depending on the value of Y-axis. Say,
the value is in range 0-30 show the data point in green colour,
the value is in range 31-40 show the data point in yellow colour,
the value is in range 41-60 show the data point in red colour etc.
I am using D3 for the first time. Also, In my code I'll be fetching data dynamically(to be specific) from back-end json file. At the back-end, there is a parameter named e(dependent on data value of Y-axis) which ranges from 0 to 3 and accordingly colour code is set at front-end depending on the which value e has. Also, the e parameter will wary for different scenarios of Y axis(Sales, Tax). For sales, 0 means 110-150, but for Tax, 0 means 50-90.Can anyone help me with this?
[Expected line chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJFWn.png)

Comment: post what you have tried so far

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cycea2pz/ For this I have referred http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-charting-directives-using-angularjs-d3-js/. I am a newbie in AngularJS and D3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to color the circle nodes for the y axis values (In my example below its data `close`):

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .style("fill", function(d){
       if (d.close < 100)
           return "red";
       if (d.close < 200)
           return "brown";
       if (d.close < 300)
           return "green";
       if (d.close < 400)
           return "blue";
       if (d.close < 500)
           return "yellow" ;  
       if (d.close < 600)
           return "pink" ;       
       if (d.close < 700)
           return "orange" ;  
    })
```

For angular you need to make this as directive...

**EDIT**
I have added a div for showing tooltip like below

```
<div id="mytooltip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; visibility: hidden; top: 82px; left: 81px;">
    <div id="ttclose"></div>
    <div id="ttdate"></div>
</div>
```

Then on move event you can show and set values as below:

```
.on("mouseover", function () {
                return d3.select("#mytooltip").style("visibility", "visible"); //making the tooltip visible
            })
                .on("mousemove", function (d) {
                console.log()
                d3.select("#mytooltip").style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1] + 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 10) + "px");
                d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#ttdate").text(function () {
                    return d.date; //setting the date values to tooltip
                });
                d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#ttclose").text(function () {
                    return d.close; //setting the date values to tooltip
                });
                return;
            })
                .on("mouseout", function () {
                return d3.select("#mytooltip").style("visibility", "hidden"); //hidding the tooltip
            });
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kyjdu7ra/7/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Cyril. This is not exactly what I am looking for. In my code I'll be fetching data dynamically(to be specific) from back-end json file. At the back-end, there is a parameter named e(dependent on data value of Y-axis) which ranges from 0 to 3  and accordingly colour code is set at front-end depending on the which value e has. Also, the e parameter will wary for different scenarios(Sales, Tax). For sales, 0 means 110-150, but for Tax, 0  means 50-90. Can you modify your code using AngularJS for this please? I am a newbie for AngularJS and D3.js.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle with angular+d3 this will set you rolling...again I cannot handle your business logic since i don't know about your dataset. That is something for you to handle.

Comment: Note that you can do this much more elegantly by using a [quantize scale or similar](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/29bccce80df0f253c97e).

Comment: @Cyril Can you please help me with the code to add tooltip with value and time on hover of every circle, X-axis and Y-axis title. I tried this  svg.selectAll("dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 3.5).append("svg:title")..text(function(d) { return d.x; }); but it doesn't work

Comment: @Wini added the comment in the code section and update the fiddle :)

Comment: @Cyril thanks yaa...but the updated code doesn't seem to work in fiddle as well as on my project. :(

Comment: well the fiddle wrks hover on teh circle you will get the tool tip

Comment: What?...no it's really not working on fiddle, I refreshed the page so many times to check. Which browser are you using?

Comment: it should now wrk on FF